# removeClass JQUERY no funciona

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, asp.net-mvc

Estoy usando **ASP.NET** para hacer un formualrio, pero necesito quitarle la clase **`disable`**, estoy usando **JQUERY**, y necesito quitarse a varias etiquetas que conforman mi objeto , pero no estoy teniendo mucho éxito.

Las objetos de los cuales quiero afectar son

```
btn-group bootstrap-select disabled form-control has-feedback-left
```

y

```
btn dropdown-toggle disabled btn-defaul
```

```js
function RemoveClass() {

  var selectCon;
  selectCon = $('.btn .dropdown-toggle .disabled .btn-default');
  $(selectCon ).removeClass('.disabled');

}
```

```html
<div id="selectx">
  <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select disabled form-control has-feedback-left">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle disabled btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="ldClientes" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true" title="HYCSA"><span class="filter-option pull-left">HYCSA</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox">
      <div class="bs-searchbox"><input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Buscar" role="textbox" aria-label="Search"></div>
      <!--esto no es relevante-->
      <select id="ldClientes" name="lstClientes" data-c-variable="idCliente" data-c-campobase="true" data-c-ctr="true" data-live-search="true" type="text" class="form-control has-feedback-left" data-p-condatos="true" tabindex="-98" data-c-plugin="selectpicker"
        data-p-temp1="1">
        <!--esto no es relevante-->ni esto
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Usa toggle en lugar de remove, asi cada vez que llamas add o retira la class de tu input. http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando usas los selectores CSS en jQuery, el punto `.` indica que es una clase. Pero no necesitas ese punto en el método `removeClass`.

Por otro lado, tu selector es incorrecto, prueba sin espacios entre las clases:

```
function RemoveClass() {

  var selectCon;
  selectCon = $('.btn.dropdown-toggle.disabled.btn-default');
  $(selectx).removeClass('disabled');

}
```

el motivo es porque (usando un ejemplo más sencillo)

`'div .btn'` busca elementos con la clase `btn` que estén **dentro** de un `div`

`'div.btn'` busca elementos que sean `div` **y** que tengan la clase `btn`

PS: ¿Has pensado en sencillamente añadir un id al elemento?

Comment: he intentado esto pero cuando inspecciono el objeto nuevamente sigue disabled

Comment: cuando busco el objeto **selectCon** esta undefined

Answer (score 1):

Para seleccionar (o filtrar por) las clases CSS del mismo nivel, tienes que quitar el espacio, por ejemplo:

```
 <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select disabled form-control has-feedback-left">
```

sería `.btn-group.bootstrap-select.disabled.form-control.has-feedback-left`

```
 <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle disabled btn-default"
```

sería  `.btn.dropdown-toggle.disabled.btn-default`

si pones espacios asume que es un child, ejemplo:

```
 <div class"padre">
    <p class="hijo tio"><span class="nieto"></span></p>
    <p class="hijo"><span class="nieto"></span></p>
```

para seleccionar el `<p>` usas `.padre .hijo` para seleccionar los `<span>` usas `.padre .hijo .nieto` ó `.padre .nieto`. Asimismo si buscas `.padre.hijo` ó `.hijo .tio` no vas a encontrar elementos, el primer `<p>` sería `.hijo.tio` ó `.padre .tio`.

Sin espacios = mismo nivel, con espacios = baja un nivel.

Volviendo a tu ejemplo:

```
 selectCon = $('.btn.dropdown-toggle.disabled.btn-default');
```

ó mas genérico

```
 selectCon = $('.btn.disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $elementos = $(".btn-group.bootstrap-select.disabled.form-control.has-
feedback-left")
$elementos.add(".btn.dropdown-toggle.disabled.btn-
defaul").removeClass("disabled")
```

Puedes ocupar .add() para añadir otro objecto a tu variable y remover la clase disabled

Answer (score 0):

yo recomiendo por orden usar siempre un id o class para asi encontrar mas facil los objetos en jquery por ejemplo id="btnClientes" y asi nada mas seria poner
$("#btnClientes").removeClass("disabled")

Answer (score -1):

No tiene caso que hagas un selector de varios elementos si solo buscas quitar la clase `disabled`. Mejor itera la clase `disabled` de los elementos que la contengan, los demás no importan. Te dejo un ejemplo

```js
$(function(){

  $(document).on('click', '#btn',function(){
    
    $('.disabled').each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('disabled');
    });
  
  })

})
```

```css
.disabled{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="foo bar poo disabled">
<input class="foo  disabled">
<input class="foo poo disabled">
<input class=" bar poo disabled">
<input class="foo bar poo disabled">
<input class=" bar disabled">
<input class="foo bar poo disabled">
<input class="foo bar">
<input class="poo disabled">

<input type="button" id="btn" value="quitar">
```